# Shinydashboard Dynamic TabPanel

Tags: r, shiny, shinydashboard

I have a similar question to the one that I recently asked regarding dynamic bullet points: [ShinyDashboard Dynamic Bullet Points](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52938451/shinydashboard-dynamic-bullet-points/52951506?noredirect=1#comment92813078_52951506)

But this time is in regards to dynamic tabpanels.  Basically I want to generate dynamic tabpanels regarding data that meet certain criteria.  Here is a simplified example of what I am trying to solve:

```
nba_teams <- data.frame(team = c("Bulls", "Nuggets", "Celtics", "Lakers"),
                    conference = c("Eastern", "Western", "Eastern", 
                                   "Western"),
                    player_over_30 = c("Y","N","N","Y"),
                    date_team_formed = c(1966-01-01,1967-01-01,1946-06- 
                                         06,1947-01-01))
```

With this dummy data I want to create two tabpanels based upon data for the Western conference teams.  Then, to display the date that they were formed and if they have a player that is over 30: display a font awesome icon and reference the data to their team page.

If I was to hard code it I could do it by the following code:

```
library(shinydashboard)
UI <- dashboardPage(
      dashboardHeader(),
      dashboardSidebar(),
      dashboardBody(

fluidRow(
 tabBox(
 title = "Western Conference Details",
 id = "tabset2", height = "200px", width = 12,
 tabPanel("Nuggets", "Nuggets Details", 
     dateInput("date1_val", label = h3("Formation Date"), value = "1967-01- 
      01")),
 tabPanel("Lakers", "Lakers Details", uiOutput("Lakers"),icon = 
 icon("sticky-note"),
     dateInput("date1_val", label = h3("Formation Date"), value = "1947-10- 
  01"))
  ))))

server <- function(input,output,session) {

 Lakers_URL <- a("Lakers Player Detail",
              href = "https://www.nba.com/lakers")
 output$Lakers <- renderUI({
   tagList("Lakers",Lakers_URL)
 })
}
shinyApp(UI, server)
```

But as data in the table changes the code will also have to be constantly updated to reflect changes which won't be able to maintained.

I started to go down this road for the UI portion of the code, but am stuck on how to be able to reference a UI output when they won't be needed on every observation and even with that removed it doesn't fully render the date information:

```
UI <- dashboardPage(
    dashboardHeader(),
    dashboardSidebar(),
    dashboardBody(

      fluidRow(
        tabBox(
          title = "Western Conference Details",
          id = "tabset2", height = "200px", width = 12,
          lapply(1:nrow(nba_teams), function(x){
            if(nba_teams$conference[x]=="Western"){


return(tabPanel(nba_teams$team[x],paste(nba_teams$team[x],"Formation Date"),
                          dateInput("date1_val", label = 
h3("Formation_Date"),
                                    value = 
nba_teams$date_team_formed[x])))}})))))
```

Any thoughts on how to proceed?  Thanks!

Comment: What is `Model_List` in your last UI? and please check the code, there are also some parentesis missing.

Comment: That should have been deleted.  I should have had (1:nrow(nba_teams)).  Thanks for the type correcting on the missing parenthesis

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you can transform your data.frame to a nested list structure you can generate `tabPanels` dynamically with `lapply`and `do.call`. Maybe this could help you:

```
nba_teams <- list(list(Title = "Bulls", Content = list("Eastern",
                                                       dateInput("date1_val",
                                                                 label = h3("Formation Date"), 
                                                                 value = "1967-01-01"))),
                  list(Title = "Nuggets", Content = "Western"),
                  list(Title = "Celtics", Content = "Eastern"),
                  list(Title = "Lakers", Content = list("Western", 
                                                        dateInput("date1_val1", 
                                                                  label = h3("Formation Date"), 
                                                                  value = "1947-10-01"),
                                                        icon = icon("sticky-note")))
)

library(shinydashboard)
library(shiny)

UI <- dashboardPage(
  dashboardHeader(),
  dashboardSidebar(),
  dashboardBody(
    uiOutput("panels")
  )
)

server <- function(input,output,session) {

  output$panels <- renderUI({
    pan = lapply(1:length(nba_teams), function(i) 
        tabPanel(nba_teams[[i]]$Title, nba_teams[[i]]$Content))
    do.call(tabBox,pan)
  })

}
shinyApp(UI, server)
```

Comment: This is great, I am going to try this with my real dataset.  Thanks!